# How large can a datasource be before a DataGridView gets into problems?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm using VS2010, C#  with a plain old forms application, a DataGridView and get problems.

The applications scans a file builds a DataSet with one table in it and uses a BindingSourse object and a DataGridView (among others) to present the data.

The file varies in size from a few KB up to a GB or more. The content is ascii text and line oriented. The number of lines is loosly related to the file size.

This all works fine but now I have a file of 45 Mb, not big, but with 627.341 lines in it. The application can scan the file without any problem. The moment I bind the DataSet to the BindingSource object the application stops.

If I disconnect the DataGridView from the BindingSource and then run the application it continues when I conenct the DataSet to the BindingSource and the rest of the application appears to respond normal.

My conclusion: A DataGridView cannot handle a datasource with 627.341 records.
I already tweaked the DataGridView not to scan the whole DataSet, for instance `AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells` but to no good.

I'm not using the DataGridView in 'virtual mode', I don't know how to do that and still use a BindingSource.

Questions:

- What is a good estimate on how many records a DataGridView can handle?
- This estimate likely machine dependant, so how can I make a reliable estimate for it?
- What settings on de DataGridView object have an impact on this?
- Is it possible to use a DataGridView in 'virtual mode' and still use a BindingSource for the content?

Any advise or suggestion is welcome, I'm lost for solutions at the moment.

Kind regards,
Andre Steeenveld.

---

Following the advise of Sebastian Schulz I got it working.
I consider this question as 'closed' but have no reply to give it a tick.

Comment: if you use DataGridView.VirtualMode then you can have millions of records without a problem. but then you're not expected to use bound data set. They are opposites. You don't set DataSource, but just set the RowCount property. provide an event handler for .CellValueNeeded Event. You need to set .VirtualMode property to true first, probably in designer. the default is false, if you leave it as it is you will get an exception, saying you cannot set RowCount. Probably you'll have to manually initialize grid's columns. You should also use bool DoubleBuffered property to enhance performance.

Comment: @Sevastian Schulz: And if I want to use the BindingSource the CellValueNeeded event must make connection with it. It's worth a try.

Comment: In the cellvalueneeded event you retrieve the desired property of the datasource (by datasource I mean a collection of elements not bound to the datagridview). The event has column and row as eventargs.

Comment: @Sebastian Schulz: I had the DataGridView on 'virtual mode' before but rearanged it to a BindingSource when I needed more.

Comment: @Sebastian Schulz: Got it working, I consider this question now as answered.